# S3 key organization best practices - UUID, PK, or name?

Tags: amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I've created an S3 bucket for some files I'm storing. We're using Rails ActiveStorage to back it.

Our app has accounts and users. The account generates two documents a month we want to save to the account. Users can generate reports that are saved to the account as well.

The account schema has the following columns:

```
id    # the primary key.
uuid  # the global ID that links all accounts across all apps.
name  # the name we show to users and assign to the account.
```

We currently store all attached files in the bucket's root, but we want to make the structure more sensible and less cluttered.

Ideally, this would be readable in the bucket, so we've been considering using the `name` - but there's no promise that this will change. Fortunately, ActiveStorage will continue to track the old keys if the name does change.

For example:

```
/accounts/[name]/uploads/file-[hash].ext
```

Are there some best practices on how to best structure this? Drawbacks? How do you structure this in your apps?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed, there are some [best practices for design patterns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/optimizing-performance.html). Specifically, you should avoid saving all your objects in the bucket's root, especially if you expect to have a large number of objects. Why? Because you can achieve **3,500 PUT/COPY/POST/DELETE or 5,500 GET/HEAD requests per second per partitioned Amazon S3 prefix**. So, if all your objects are in the bucket's root they'll all share the same **prefix**, therefore you can only achieve what I've described before.

As to how to structure the bucket, there is no best practices. You can do it in several ways and they all can be right. Just do what you feel is the best approach for your application.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but it’s a bit off topic. There’s plenty of documentation on bucket naming and performance, but little on good practices on organizing the keys themselves.

Comment: I think it's kind of hard to come up with best practices to organize the keys because they ultimately depend on the applications you are building. For example, access patterns to the objects, security controls you may want to apply, etc. Sorry I wasn't of any help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to both keep your price down and get the files neatly ordered, I would suggest the following strategy:

- partition the files by account
- do a secondary partition by user

The final structure would be something like:

```
s3://path-to-bucket/account/user
```

This would help locating files significantly (you won't need to scan through the whole bucket), and you'll also be able to devise long-term storage strategies (e.g. putting less used files into a cheaper storage class).

If the question relates to whether you should use PK / UUID / name for the partitions, [there's no difference](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-performance-tips-tricks-seattle-hiring-event/) - I would go for what needs the least code transformations.

From shared link:

> We frequently see new workloads introduced to S3 where content is
> organized by user ID, or game ID, or other similar semi-meaningless
> identifier. Often these identifiers are incrementally increasing
> numbers, or date-time constructs of various types. The unfortunate
> part of this naming choice where S3 scaling is concerned is two-fold:
> First, all new content will necessarily end up being owned by a single
> partition (remember the request rates from above…). Second, all the
> partitions holding slightly older (and generally less ‘hot’) content
> get cold much faster than other naming conventions, effectively
> wasting the available operations per second that each partition can
> support by making all the old ones cold over time.

Comment: Maybe consider how the data will be consumed in the majority of cases - there may be value in organising your partitioning such that it allows your application to read the least volume of data to deliver your results. This is not always easy to assess, granted.